# if statement not working batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I have this batch file that has something like this:

```
if "%1" == "dev" (
   rem do something ...
)
else (
   rem do something else ...
)
```

and I have this `echo` command above the `if-else` block

```
echo "%1" >> test.txt
```

The content of `test.txt` after running is `"dev"` (with the double quotes).
However, it always hit the `else` block instead of the `if` block. I checked that by putting another `echo` command inside the `else ()`

Comment: You've never read the help message of `if /?`, have you? there are examples how `if`/`else` works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`else` have to be in same line of `)` and `(`

`IF /?` show you this usage:

```
if exist filename (
    del filename 
) else (
    echo filename not found
)
```

Or in 1 line:

```
if exist filename ( del filename ) else ( echo filename not found )
```

Or in 2 lines

```
if exist filename ( del filename 
) else ( echo filename not found )
```

2 lines variation

```
if exist filename ( del filename ) else ( 
echo filename not found )
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is quite trivial! Simply move `else (` one line up:

```
if "%1" == "dev" (
   rem do something ...
) else (
   rem do something else ...
)
```

Now it should work.